# Конвертировать HTML, содержащий <img> в PDF используя iTextSharp и vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itextsharp

Очень нужна помощь! Пробую ковертировать HTML документ, содержащий  в PDF используя iTextSharp и vb.net - работает без проблем. Но как только добавляю img тэг, дает эксепшн - Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag img. Причем это касается всех самозакрывающихся тэгов. Не подскажете как решить проблему? Заранее спасибо!

HTML

```
 <div id = "Grid">
  <img src="img/q12.gif" />
 </div>
```

vb.net

```
  Dim sr As New StringReader(Request.Form(hfGridHtml.UniqueID))
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New 
  FileStream(Context.Server.MapPath("~/out.pdf"), FileMode.CreateNew))
pdfDoc.Open()
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:61834/ejik.pdf")
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.End()
```

JS

```
$(function () {
$("[id*=btnExport]").click(function () {
    $("[id*=hfGridHtml]").val($("#Grid").html());
});
});
```

Код, конечно, кривой и примитивный, но дело как раз не в нем, он просто для примера, а конкретно в конвертации img тэга.

Comment: А можно пример без сервера? Просто консольное приложение с захардкоженной строкой с разметкой и сохранением файла output.pdf.